# Using an AJAX call to asp page then using JSON data returned from page to populate a select box with options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-select

I am trying to populate a `select` box based on JSON data returned from my ASP page: http://accdbmgr-001-site1.etempurl.com/ajax.asp

This is the data returned from the Server:

```js
{
  "data": [{
    "Lastname": "Roussel",
    "Firstname": "Donald"
  }, {
    "Lastname": "Sabourin",
    "Firstname": "Manon"
  }, {
    "Lastname": "Kelly",
    "Firstname": "Bruce"
  }]
}
```

However, for some reason it just doesn't seem to be able to add my JSON data into the select box. I'd like for the options to appear as: `Lastname, FirstName`

```html
<div id="test"></div>
<form>
  <select id="select1"></select>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('http://accdbmgr-001-site1.etempurl.com/ajax.asp', {
    category: 'client',
    type: 'premium'
  }, function(data) {
    alert("success")
    //$("#test").html(data)
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for (i in obj) {
      $('#select1').append(new Option(obj[i].Firstname, obj[i].Lastname));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try `for (i in obj.data)`

Comment: first like @phuzi said you need to travel through obj.data instead of object, and then you need to build a string to pass to new option like this

 `${obj[i].Firstname}, ${obj[i].Lastname}` 

because the first one is the display one and the second one is the value behind, so they will not appear both as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is because you're looping through `obj`, when you instead need to loop through the `obj.data` array.

Also note that you can use `map()` to build an array of strings which you can then `append()` once to make the logic more succinct and more performant.

Finally your code is currently creating an `option` element with `Firstname` as the text of the element, and `Lastname` as the `value`. If you want the text to be in `Lastname, Firstname` format you need to set the text to that explicitly. Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  "data": [{
    "Lastname": "Roussel",
    "Firstname": "Donald"
  }, {
    "Lastname": "Sabourin",
    "Firstname": "Manon"
  }, {
    "Lastname": "Kelly",
    "Firstname": "Bruce"
  }]
}

var options = obj.data.map(function(item) {
  return `<option>${item.Lastname}, ${item.Firstname}</option>`;
});
$('#select1').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<form>
  <select id="select1"></select>
</form>
```

Also note that `JSON.parse()` is not needed if you set `dataType: 'json'` on the request, or use `$.getJSON()`